# Is this considered a good practice in OOP?

Tags: oop, methods

I am trying to learn the best practices for methods in OOP in general. So lets say I have this code (C# by the way):

```
class Player
{
    private Connection conn;
    public Update(Keyboard key)
    {
        if(key.IsPressedKey("a"))
        {
            // should move
            conn.SendPacketMovement(Movement.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

If I wanted to call a method inside the Connection class instance, what should I do? I dont want to add a return value to the Update method because it doesn't seem like a really good practice.

What should I do in that case, when I want several classes to do different things? Should I use delegates and events? If so, how do I subscribe to them. Should I subscribe to them when I create the instance of Player?

Comment: I don't understand what are you asking. May you better explain it?

Comment: There's no obvious reason for not having a return value.  Use a return value if you need one.  @silli is right; it's not clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: inside the Player class instance u mean ?

Comment: I am trying to ask how would be the best way to communicate between methods. calling methods of instances inside methods doesnt seem as a really good approach

Comment: Why do you think calling methods of collaborating objects is a bad idea? That's the very essence of OOP, it's also known as "message passing".

Answer (score 1):

in the end a method is always invoked in the scope of another method. However delegation is indeed a good practice. For instance if you have a class behavior that may be implemented differently by different delegates you could apply the Chain of Responsibility pattern to reduce coupling http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern